# Как объявить указатель на функцию в C/C++

Tags: c, c++

Как объявить указатель на функцию в C/C++

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Необходимо придерживаться следующей формы объявления:

```
typedef тип_возвращаемого_значения (*имя_указ)(список_параметров_функции);
```

Например:

```
typedef int (*pfn)(int param1, void * param2);
```

Comment: это еще не указатель на функцию,  а его тип

Answer (score 6):

Начиная с [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) можно объявить через `using`:

```
using name = retType(*)(params);
```

Пример:

```
void f(int, int) {}           // функция приемлимой сигнатуры 
using FP = void(*)(int, int); // объявление типа указатель на функцию
FP fp = f;                    // определение и инициализация
fp(42, 100500);               // вызов функции через указатель
```

Answer (score 4):

```
std::function
```

Очень удобная вещь ( но, конечно, это не касается Pure C, кой был в метках ). Тут Вам и указатели на функции, и на методы класса, и на функторы (!), и всякие мутки с bind и place-холдерами.

[Спека](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)